# How do I change the uib-datepicker-popup button bar?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [uib-datepicker-popup](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup) and I would like to change the button bar. Right now it uses `.btn-info`, `.btn-danger` and `.btn-success` for the 'today', 'clear' and 'close' buttons respectively. How could I change these to be other button classes, such as `.btn-default` (with hopefully not much work)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the datepicker template.  Default one is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/datepickerPopup/popup.html

Use the `templateUrl` directive like this:

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" template-url="path/to/template.html" />
```

Comment: Thanks mate! The default datepicker template especially helped :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add the `datepicker-popup-template-url` property

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" **datepicker-popup-template-url**="path/to/template.html" />
```

Then, you need to create a template.html

I added a custom button which is setting date 31/12/9999. Template is below

```
<ul class="uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu uib-position-measure" dropdown-nested ng-if="isOpen" style="left: 0px; top: 43px; display: block;"  ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <li ng-transclude></li>
  <li ng-if="showButtonBar" class="uib-button-bar">
    <span class="btn-group pull-left">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info uib-datepicker-current" ng-click="select('today', $event)" ng-disabled="isDisabled('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger uib-clear" ng-click="select('31/12/9999', $event)">31/12/9999</button>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right uib-close" ng-click="close($event)">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```