# Angular ui-bootstrap datepicker change theme

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a angular datepicker that shows like this -

[image: Bootstrap Datepicker]

This datepicker is huge and covers up almost 30% of the screen and also, dates have huge gaps among them.

Now I suspect that this is happening because I have styled my tables and buttons for the whole project. How do I change/style my datepicker so my table and button styling does not affect the datepicker.

**P.S**: I tried styling it with `.datepicker` syntax, did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my website as well when using ui-bootstrap datepicker. The datepicker is good with many features but finding a way to customize it becomes a pain.

Coming to your problem, I have few suggestions:

- The datepicker will take the CSS that you have by default for **table, th, td, tr** in your website. Find a way to specify the styling for uib-datepicker-popup.
- Try using a custom template as mentioned in the website documentation. [Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzCXM.png)

This link will be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801772/how-do-i-change-the-uib-datepicker-popup-button-bar

Answer (score 0):

You actually need CSS tricks. like:

- Be sure your custom styles are loaded after bootstrap codes.
- Make your selector more powerful, like `#someContainer div.uib-datepicker {...}` or `#someContainer div.uib-datepicker > table > tbody > tr > td {...}` (well, doing this with css-preprocessors are quite easy)
- easily edit ui-boostrap js code and add an extra class to its template, and follow above structure

---

By the way, [**`adm-dtp`**](https://github.com/AmirkabirDataMiners/ADM-dateTimePicker) module might be more helpful.

Comment: I know I do need a CSS trick, but I can not figure out what. Also, switching to a different calendar will be my last resort

Comment: @ThatBird do my three suggestions :)