# Change button labels for AngularUi Bootstrap's datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I need to change the Today, Clear and Close button's label. I'm looking for something like the `clear-text`, `close-text` and `current-text` options for the datepickerPopup directive or for a good alternative workaround.

Tried to change with Jquery, but the buttons don't have unique class or id, so I cannot create a unique selector for each button.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801772/how-do-i-change-the-uib-datepicker-popup-button-bar)

Comment: @tomek550 I need to change the labels, not the classes, and on the simple datepicker, not the datepicker-popup.

Comment: did you solve this

Comment: @ModarNa you can just copy the current template to a custom template url with changed labels, see the `template-url` setting.

Comment: Thanks @neptune ill try that